# jquery UI date picker is not storing values in database in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui-datepicker

I can click the date from calender and the selected value is showing in textbox but sometimes the values are not storing into database. I'm using three date picker in a single form and I don't know why it's not working properly.

here is my code:

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'});
$( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'});
$( "#datepicker3" ).datepicker({format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'});
});
</script>
<h4><%= f.label :DOB, class:'required' %></h4>
<h4><%= f.text_field :dob, :id => "datepicker1", :placeholder => "date of birth" %></h4>

<h4><%= f.label :Start_date, class:'required' %></h4>
<h4><%= f.text_field :start_date, :id => "datepicker2", :placeholder => "start date" %> 
</h4>

<h4><%= f.label :End_date %></h4>
<h4><%= f.text_field :end_date, :id => "datepicker3", :placeholder => "end date" %></h4>
```

Any help is much appreciated,

My controller

```
def index @employees = Employee.all
puts Date.parse(params[:end_date])
@employees = Employee.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
end
```

Comment: Sometimes or all the time?

Comment: show the code that puts it in the database.

Comment: @Baloo: sometimes only..sometime all the values are storing in database but sometimes it stores only 2 or 3 values.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DpmeB/ - referred this site

Comment: just add the controller code..

Comment: @Santino'Sonny'Corleone: i didn't add any special code in controller for date picker.

Comment: @user3733874 here the code seems fine then..

Comment: @user3733874 is your table column type date or string?

Comment: @Santino'Sonny'Corleone: but why all the 3 values are not storing in database? is their any condition to use three date picker in single form?? i didn't add validation yet :(

Comment: @Santino'Sonny'Corleone: it is in Date format.

Comment: ok..did u check ur logs for errors? coz i think u might have to parse the date parameter as DATE using Date.parse(params[:date]) and then put it in the database

Comment: @user3733874 did u solve it?

Comment: @Santino'Sonny'Corleone: no..

Comment: @Santino'Sonny'Corleone:in logs it shows "WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true" then i  googled and added "thin" gem.but still im getting the same error.

Comment: just puts and see the date paramter in your controler..see if it comes on your controller first..

Comment: @user3733874 ...check my last comment

Comment: @Santino'Sonny'Corleone:I have edited my controller page.but didn't work puts statement.kindly check it.

Comment: @user3733874 next, `date = Date.parse(params[:end_date]),d1 = date.strftime("%F")` and now put d1 in the database..checck if it goes.

Comment: @Santino'Sonny'Corleone: Thanks for your reply.i did a small mistake in application.html.erb and i corrected my error & got the output:)